# git vscodeでのterminal操作、 evalの後の操作方法

Tags: git, vscode, git-bash

私のこの一連のゴタゴタに親身になってコメントいただいている方には大変申し訳ないのですが、一度始めからやり直し、24:23頃（https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk&t=1511s）
まできてまたわからなくなってしまいました。2点明確にしたいことがあります。
①$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"がvscodeだと画像のように認識されず、stackoverflowにはGit Bashでやるといいと書いてあり、やってみたところAgent pidがきちんと表示されました。しかしその後Git Bashかvscodeかどちらでやれば良いのでしょうか。

②それから次の処理はどう行えば良いのでしょうか。これはid_ed25519をtestkeyに変えるべきでしょうか。
「Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent　②Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent. キーを別の名前で作成した場合、または別の名前の既存のキーを追加する場合は、コマンドの id_ed25519 を秘密キー ファイルの名前に置き換えます。

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519」
https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: VS Codeで git bash使うのはどうですか？参考[Terminal Shell Integration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration#_manual-installation)
あと terminal.integrated.profiles.windows https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles

Comment: ありがとうございます。提供いただいたサイトを使って統合できました！

Answer (score 1):

(YouTubeなどに挙がっている)非公式の解説を参照する必要はありません。
質問文中にもリンクされていますが、[公式の説明](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)のみに従って手続きを進めてください。

鍵を生成したのであれば、次のセクション[Add a new SSH key(GitHub アカウントへの新しい SSH キーの追加)](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)に書かれている手順でその鍵を登録します。