# git Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git

freeCodeCampのYouTube Git and GitHub for Beginners - Crash Courseの25:45頃にgit push origin master(私の場合はmain）をしたいのですが、下記の通りPermission denied (publickey) と出てしまいました。

```
 PS C:\Users\FMV\git> git push origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

そこでこちらのサイトを参考に直そうとしていました。
https://ormcat.net/blog/20210509_github-denied-publickey/

GitHub との疎通テストを行う　→　NG パターン
SSH コマンドのデバッグログで鍵を確認する　→　$ ssh -vT git@github.com
までやった結果が下の結果です。

```
PS C:\Users\FMV\git> ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
PS C:\Users\FMV\git> ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.27.177.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-98e6a628
debug1: no match: babeld-98e6a628
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:nz+XwOvg8KN+x4tgzz7eNc77ThGLQn3UOJKECkWjwK0
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:+fvNB2EJB6PpPULfb7cCEuS/9vR/Bq5409GjY62Pqq8
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:nz+XwOvg8KN+x4tgzz7eNc77ThGLQn3UOJKECkWjwK0
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:+fvNB2EJB6PpPULfb7cCEuS/9vR/Bq5409GjY62Pqq8
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\FMV/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

その後、
秘密鍵がそこにあるか ?　と　秘密鍵と公開鍵の組み合わせは正しいか ?
をやった結果がこちらです。

```
PS C:\Users\FMV\git> ls ~/.ssh

    Directory: C:\Users\FMV\.ssh

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          2022/09/24    18:45                demo-repo
-a---          2022/09/24    14:15          12288 .config.swp
-a---          2022/09/24    18:42            419 id_ed25519
-a---          2022/09/24    18:42            109 id_ed25519.pub
-a---          2022/09/24    18:29           2610 id_rsa
-a---          2022/09/24    18:29            574 id_rsa.pub
-a---          2022/09/24    13:18            832 known_hosts
-a---          2022/09/24    10:08             92 known_hosts.old

PS C:\Users\FMV\git> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\FMV/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

既にYouTubeでtestkeyというkeyを作ったのでここから進めて良いのか、またどう対処すれば良いのかわからず止まっています。

アドバイスよろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/91301/2808)でも回答しましたが、外部のサイトの説明は参考にせずに、公式サイトの手順に沿って作業してください。
余計な混乱を招くだけですし、他者(回答候補者)から見て質問者が実際に何をやったのかが把握できません。

---

[`id_ed25519.pub` を GitHub へ登録する](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account#adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-account)必要がありますが、この操作は行われたでしょうか。
その上でこの問題が出た場合、(説明文にもある通り)[トラブルシューティング](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey)を参照し、それでも問題が解決しなかった場合、状況をこちらに記載してください。

Answer (score -1):

> Permission denied (publickey).

ってのは、接続鍵が間違っている、あるいは接続鍵の設定が間違っている、場合に出ます。
そこらへんみなおしてみては